# One of my tests fails due to some issues with using let! in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have no clue what is wrong with the following:

```
     let!(:account1) { create(:account) }

      describe ".active_between" do
        subject { Account.active_between(Date.today - 10.days, Date.today).to_a }
        it { is_expected.to eq([account1]) }
      end
```

Somehow this tests fails like this:

```
expected: [#<Account id: 2, lead_id: 2]
     got: [#<Account id: 2, lead_id: 3]
```

What could be causing the issue with the lead_id that's being changed? There's absolutely no code repsonsible for changing it.

The Factory Bot is set-up like this:

```
  factory :account do
    association :lead
  end
```

The lead factory is defined as:

```
  factory :lead do
    name 'Lead'
  end
```

Comment: how is the lead factory defined ?

Comment: I updated the question. Pretty straightforward actually.

Comment: @bo-oz did you setup `database_cleaner` ?

Comment: Yes! Could that be the problem?

Comment: did you redefine the `==` method of `Account` model?

Comment: No, no changes to `==`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other tests that change `account1`, and in particular it's `lead` in anyway? Rspec will run tests in random order so it could be a test later on that is causing it.

Regardless of that, these sorts of tests can be somewhat flaky.  Do you really want to compare the entire object or just that the IDs match? If ID match is enough then your'e test is fine and you don't have to worry about other attributes (particularly timestamps being off a smidgen)

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here unfortunately. Does it fail if you run ONLY this test?

If not, I would suggest using https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

to solve the problem and ensure that each test starts with clean database.

If that won't help, there must be something in models classes that interferes with it. If you encounter further problems, add also snippet from both models, we probably will be able to tell you more then